# MySQL - How do I store multiple date types (quarter, month, year) in one column

Tags: mysql, database, date

I have some data that the user uploads, and it need to be stored and sorted based on the period the user selected. The period should only support month-year or quarter-year, nothing else, similar to below:

```
    +----+---------+-------+
    | id | period  | data  |
    +----+---------+-------+
    |  1 | 2018-09 | test1 |
    |  2 | 2019-01 | test2 |
    |  3 | 2018-Q3 | test3 |
    |  4 | 2017-Q4 | test4 |
    +----+---------+-------+
```

I was first looking for a data type that supports date ranges, such as 2018-01-01 - 2018-03-31, which in this case would be used whenever the user selects Q1 2018, however I was not able to find such data type. I could probably use two columns to support the quarterly dates, another one for the month, and the last for the year but this doesn't feel like a good approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a calculation in SQL which can convert `2018-Q3` to `2018-01-01 - 2018-03-31` for example or do i not understanding the question?

Comment: Two dates, delimiting the start and end of the period, are probably your best option; any alternative would probably end up involving parsing data in the middle of a queries (not a good situation to put yourself in). If you really need to easily/quickly know what kind of period is being represented, a third field indicating period type could also be used. _Another alternative is separate tables for quarterly and monthly data._

Answer (score 0):

mysql provides a vast set of functions to manage dates ... so you could simply archive a reference date and  using the mysql functions.

for example using the actuale date as the date

```
 select quarter(curdate ()), month(curdate ()), year(curdate())
```

in this way you coudl avoid to store calculated range ..

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: What does "pquindi potrest semplciemnte"  mean?

Comment: @RaymondNijland  .thanks  .. wrong .. copy and past..  answer updated ..

Comment: My only concern with an approach like this would be that you cannot index function results; for example, If you needed to find all data points that a specific date fell within, or join with a "detail" table that had specific dates, the quarter|month and year values would need to be calculated for all rows... and the filter condtion's value, or joined table's values.